# Adding custom domain via REST API assigns "NULL" value for KeyVaultId

Tags: azure, rest, azure-api-management, custom-domain

I have tried to add custom domain for my apim service in azure via REST API. The custom domain gets added but the KeyVaultId is assigned with NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior if you're uploading your own certificate. If you use certificate from KeyVault keyVaultId will be set to id of that certificate.